# Jquery date picker restrict dates like 2222222/33333/444444

Tags: jquery, validation, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery Date Picker in my MVC 3 + Razor project.

I have successfully been able to use and integrate it with my project.

Using date picker now I can see that it does not allow characters like a,b...@#,$,%.. and so on. But it does allow number, to understand what I mean see the screenshot,

I think I need to make some changes in the jquery itself, but I dont know where. Please help me out on this one.

[image]

[image]

With help of marcolinux, I have used http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html, and now when I have added this to my script

```
        $(form).validate({
        rules: {
        startDate: {
        dpDate: true
        }
        }
        });
```

and imported this link

```
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have made more progress in this now
using class="dpDate" in my textbox now I am able to get a red border on my text box for input like
1212635245
111/12313/12313

now the last part I need to know is how to show a error message next to textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in an attribute readonly="readonly" 
Should solve the issue :)

Comment: I tried that, but the problem using this is I cannot remove a date once set :(

Comment: I have used read only with the example shown at
http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html, and now it works ( dancing !)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are worried about dates that are "typed" in the text box. You can hook an error checking function inside the `onClose` event fired by the datepicker:

> Allows you to define your own event when the datepicker is closed,
>   whether or not a date is selected. The function receives the selected
>   date as text ('' if none) and the datepicker instance as parameters.
>   this refers to the associated input field.

When the user types something in the text box, the datepicker will open. The onClose event will fire when the user chooses a date (valid) or when the control loses focus (date may or may not be valid). You can then check the date inside your event handler:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, instance) {
        var date;
        try {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("$.datepicker.parseDate failed");
        }
        if (!date) {
            alert("This date is not valid");
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }
});
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ePSN2/)

Answer (score 1):

this plugin will do what you ask

http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html

example

```
Validate date:   2222/22/222
results :   Please enter a valid date
```

Comment: this looks helpful, let me try this out

Answer (score 1):

try it onkeypress of textbox,

`$('#ID').keypress(function (event) {

    if (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 && this.value.length < 10 || event.charCode == 47 && (this.value.length == 2 || this.value.length == 5)) {
        if ((this.value.length == 2 || this.value.length == 5) && event.charCode != 47) {

            $(this).val(this.value + "/");

        }
    }
    else
        event.preventDefault();
});`